# ratio of sum of columns in kibana

Tags: kibana

I have data in following format

```
Date        A      B
20150901    23.4   2.4
20150901    245    22
20150901    21     2.4
20150902    243    4.2
20150902    7.5    1.2
20150903    .54    8.4
```

what I want do is `SUM(colA)/SUM(colB)` for each date. I am using kibana for this but I can not find a way to do this. All it shows is `SUM(colA)` but I cannot save it to use for finding the ratio.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You must use scripted field, create a new field, and then in that field you will have the sum of a + b of each data. Then when you discover data or do some graph only select the data that where you need the sum.

Comment: Can you please post your answer in detail mentioning the ways to create a scripted field and how to include the scripted field in Kibana for visualization?

Comment: To create a scripted field you go to your kibana board, go to setting, click the index where yo want to create a new scripted field, and there you click over scripted field. To visualization  the new field appear as a new field in the list of fields.

Comment: Can you mention an example of how to provide input to scripted field? or any tutorial mentioning how to create input for scripted fields?

Comment: only do the following thing doc['some_field'].value vere some field is the field where you want to do anything, for example in the case above: doc['colA'].value + doc['colB'].value.

Comment: In the above question requirement is to find:
sum(colA)/sum(colB)
and as per your answer, you are suggesting:
sum(colA + colB)

Answer (score 0):

This was challenge I had too.
Have a look also at this great kibana plugin:
https://github.com/datasweet-fr/kibana-datasweet-formula

The original discussion can also be found here:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2646

It supports several functions of aggregated metrics.
It worked for my case of ratios of aggregated sums over time, similar to your case.